# phpwordとtcpdfを使用したwordファイルからのpdf作成で一部が文字化けする。

Tags: php, 文字化け

以下のルールで作成したwordファイル(docx)をphp(Laravel)を介してpdfに変換しようとしています。一部のファイルで文字化けが発生していしまい、原因が分からず困っています。同様の現象を解決した方がいらっしゃれば助けていただけないでしょうか。

使用しているライブラリはphpwordとtcpdfです。

- 1行目をMSゴシック、2行目をMS明朝で入力。
- 左インデントは使用しない。
- tcpdfでのフォント指定は'kozminproregular'

[発生している現象]
2行目のMS明朝の行がpdf上では？マークとなる。
全てのファイルで再現する訳ではなく、顧客がword2016で作成した一部のファイルでのみ再現。

[現在行った調査]
文字化け箇所とそうではないテキストをギリギリまで削る
->　再現する。

新規ファイル作成で同じ内容で同じフォントを指定する
->　再現しない。

phpwordがwordファイルを解析したときのxml一時ファイルでは文字化けしていない。

元のwordファイル
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

変換後のpdf
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

使用バージョン
"tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.5"
"phpoffice/phpword": "^0.18.3",

よろしくお願いします。
必用な情報などがございましたらご指摘いただければ幸いです。